# I'm supposed to be reading data from a file and dumping part of it into another text file. But I'm having an error

Tags: java

//the code below is constantly giving me errors since its not reading the file
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

```
    String file="marc21.txt";
    String a;

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("marc22.txt")));

        while(br.readLine()!=null){
            //obtaining first five characters of file
            file.substring(0, 4);
            //saving substring to value
            a=file.substring(0, 4);

            //converting a to integer
            int x=Integer.parseInt(a);
            System.out.println("x is "+x);

            //taking record to marc21 to another file marc22
            bw.write(file.substring(0, x));
            bw.write("\n");
            bw.close();

        }
```

Comment: You have to do *this* and *that* to fix it. If you like more descriptive answers, than write more descriptive questions.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that this Question is formal or informal homework or some other kind of learning exercise, and providing you with hints so that you can solve the problems with your code for yourself. (And LEARN!)

Hint: `file` is the name of a file ... not a line that you read from the file.

Hint 2:  what happens to the input line that you read in the following expression ...

```
  br.readLine() != null
```

... after you have tested to see if it is null?